# Microsoft.Synchronization code crashing in Unity but works in Visual C#

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, dll, synchronization

So i modified a sample code from here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/File-Synchronization-516e3ad7 a little to fit my needs. This is a console application that takes in 2 arguments, first is the source, second is destination. It's a one way sync source to destination folders.

```
// <copyright file="SyncMain.cs" company="Microsoft">
//     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
// <summary>Sample code for using the MSF File Sync Provider</summary>

using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Files;

public class FileSyncProviderSample
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length < 2 || 
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0]) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[1]) ||
            !Directory.Exists(args[0]) || !Directory.Exists(args[1]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
              "Usage: FileSyncSample [valid directory path 1] [valid directory path 2]");
            return;
        }

        string replica1RootPath = args[0];
        string replica2RootPath = args[1];

        try
        {
            // Set options for the sync operation
            FileSyncOptions options =
            FileSyncOptions.ExplicitDetectChanges |
            FileSyncOptions.RecycleDeletedFiles |
            FileSyncOptions.RecyclePreviousFileOnUpdates |
            FileSyncOptions.RecycleConflictLoserFiles;

            FileSyncScopeFilter filter = new FileSyncScopeFilter();
            filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.lnk"); // Exclude all *.lnk files

            // Explicitly detect changes on both replicas upfront, to avoid two change 
            // detection passes for the two-way sync
            DetectChangesOnFileSystemReplica(
                replica1RootPath, filter, options);
            DetectChangesOnFileSystemReplica(
                replica2RootPath, filter, options);

            // Sync in both directions
            SyncFileSystemReplicasOneWay(replica1RootPath, replica2RootPath, null, options);
            //SyncFileSystemReplicasOneWay(replica2RootPath, replica1RootPath, null, options);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nException from File Sync Provider:\n" + e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void DetectChangesOnFileSystemReplica(
            string replicaRootPath,
            FileSyncScopeFilter filter, FileSyncOptions options)
    {
        FileSyncProvider provider = null;

        try
        {
            provider = new FileSyncProvider(replicaRootPath, filter, options);
            provider.DetectChanges();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Release resources
            if (provider != null)
                provider.Dispose(); 
        }
    }

    public static void SyncFileSystemReplicasOneWay(
            string sourceReplicaRootPath, string destinationReplicaRootPath,
            FileSyncScopeFilter filter, FileSyncOptions options)
    {
        FileSyncProvider sourceProvider = null;
        FileSyncProvider destinationProvider = null;

        try
        {
            sourceProvider = new FileSyncProvider(
                sourceReplicaRootPath, filter, options);
            destinationProvider = new FileSyncProvider(
                destinationReplicaRootPath, filter, options);

            destinationProvider.AppliedChange +=
                new EventHandler<AppliedChangeEventArgs>(OnAppliedChange);
            destinationProvider.SkippedChange +=
                new EventHandler<SkippedChangeEventArgs>(OnSkippedChange);

            SyncOrchestrator agent = new SyncOrchestrator();
            agent.LocalProvider = sourceProvider;
            agent.RemoteProvider = destinationProvider;
            agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload; // Sync source to destination

            Console.WriteLine("Synchronizing changes to replica: " +
                destinationProvider.RootDirectoryPath);
            agent.Synchronize();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Release resources
            if (sourceProvider != null) sourceProvider.Dispose(); 
            if (destinationProvider != null) destinationProvider.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public static void OnAppliedChange(object sender, AppliedChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        switch(args.ChangeType)
        {
            case ChangeType.Create: 
               Console.WriteLine("-- Applied CREATE for file " + args.NewFilePath); 
               break;
            case ChangeType.Delete:
               Console.WriteLine("-- Applied DELETE for file " + args.OldFilePath); 
               break;
            case ChangeType.Update:
               Console.WriteLine("-- Applied OVERWRITE for file " + args.OldFilePath); 
               break;
            case ChangeType.Rename:
               Console.WriteLine("-- Applied RENAME for file " + args.OldFilePath + 
                                 " as " + args.NewFilePath); 
               break;
        }
    }

    public static void OnSkippedChange(object sender, SkippedChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-- Skipped applying " + args.ChangeType.ToString().ToUpper() 
              + " for " + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.CurrentFilePath) ? 
                            args.CurrentFilePath : args.NewFilePath) + " due to error");

        if (args.Exception != null)
            Console.WriteLine("   [" + args.Exception.Message + "]");
    }
}
```

It works just as expected, but when i modified the code and uses it in Unity, it crashes in editor playmode and does nothing when running the build. The crash seems to originate from agent.Synchronize();

Script in Unity

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Files;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class FileSyncTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string replica1RootPath;
    [SerializeField] private string replica2RootPath;

    [SerializeField] private KeyCode activateSyncKey = KeyCode.Keypad5;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(activateSyncKey))
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(replica1RootPath) || Directory.Exists(replica2RootPath))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Set options for the sync operation
                    FileSyncOptions options =
                    FileSyncOptions.ExplicitDetectChanges |
                    FileSyncOptions.RecycleDeletedFiles |
                    FileSyncOptions.RecyclePreviousFileOnUpdates |
                    FileSyncOptions.RecycleConflictLoserFiles;

                    FileSyncScopeFilter filter = new FileSyncScopeFilter();
                    filter.FileNameExcludes.Add("*.lnk"); // Exclude all *.lnk files

                    // Explicitly detect changes on both replicas upfront, to avoid two change 
                    // detection passes for the two-way sync
                    DetectChangesOnFileSystemReplica(
                        replica1RootPath, filter, options);
                    DetectChangesOnFileSystemReplica(
                        replica2RootPath, filter, options);

                    // Sync in both directions
                    SyncFileSystemReplicasOneWay(replica1RootPath, replica2RootPath, null, options);
                    //SyncFileSystemReplicasOneWay(replica2RootPath, replica1RootPath, null, options);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.Log("\nException from File Sync Provider:\n" + e.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("One of the dir doesn't exist");
            }
        }
    }

    public void DetectChangesOnFileSystemReplica(
            string replicaRootPath,
            FileSyncScopeFilter filter, FileSyncOptions options)
    {
        FileSyncProvider provider = null;

        try
        {
            provider = new FileSyncProvider(replicaRootPath, filter, options);
            provider.DetectChanges();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Release resources
            if (provider != null)
                provider.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void SyncFileSystemReplicasOneWay(
            string sourceReplicaRootPath, string destinationReplicaRootPath,
            FileSyncScopeFilter filter, FileSyncOptions options)
    {
        FileSyncProvider sourceProvider = null;
        FileSyncProvider destinationProvider = null;

        try
        {
            sourceProvider = new FileSyncProvider(
                sourceReplicaRootPath, filter, options);
            destinationProvider = new FileSyncProvider(
                destinationReplicaRootPath, filter, options);

            destinationProvider.AppliedChange +=
                new EventHandler<AppliedChangeEventArgs>(OnAppliedChange);
            destinationProvider.SkippedChange +=
                new EventHandler<SkippedChangeEventArgs>(OnSkippedChange);

            SyncOrchestrator agent = new SyncOrchestrator();
            agent.LocalProvider = sourceProvider;
            agent.RemoteProvider = destinationProvider;
            agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.Upload; // Sync source to destination

            Debug.Log("Synchronizing changes to replica: " +
                destinationProvider.RootDirectoryPath);
            agent.Synchronize();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Release resources
            if (sourceProvider != null) sourceProvider.Dispose();
            if (destinationProvider != null) destinationProvider.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void OnAppliedChange(object sender, AppliedChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.ChangeType)
        {
            case ChangeType.Create:
                Debug.Log("-- Applied CREATE for file " + args.NewFilePath);
                break;
            case ChangeType.Delete:
                Debug.Log("-- Applied DELETE for file " + args.OldFilePath);
                break;
            case ChangeType.Update:
                Debug.Log("-- Applied OVERWRITE for file " + args.OldFilePath);
                break;
            case ChangeType.Rename:
                Debug.Log("-- Applied RENAME for file " + args.OldFilePath +
                                  " as " + args.NewFilePath);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnSkippedChange(object sender, SkippedChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.Log("-- Skipped applying " + args.ChangeType.ToString().ToUpper()
              + " for " + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.CurrentFilePath) ?
                            args.CurrentFilePath : args.NewFilePath) + " due to error");

        if (args.Exception != null)


     Debug.Log("   [" + args.Exception.Message + "]");
    }
}
```

I have copied the required DLLs into the project folders, below are the DLLs i copied.

- FeedSync.21.dll
- FileSyncProvider21.dll
- MetaStore21.dll
- Microsoft.Synchronization.dll
- Microsoft.Synchronization.Files.dll
- Microsoft.Synchronization.MetadataStorage.dll
- Microsoft.Synchronization.SimpleProviders.dll
- Msfdb.dll
- Msfdbqp.dll
- Msfdbse.dll
  -SimpleProviders21.dll
  -Synchronization21.dll

Editor.log
- https://pastebin.com/3MnNFY4z

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What does "crash" mean in this case? The Unity editor crashes? You get some sort of error? Have you looked in the editor.log file to see if there is more information? Have you considered that Unity really does not like you moving files around outside the facilities provided by the editor while it is running?

Comment: It just outright quits without any error in the editor console. This appeared in the editor.log

https://pastebin.com/3MnNFY4z

Im just moving files between folders outside of unity